# Document class_attribute with yard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yard

How do I tell yard to document class attributes that are set up with Rails' [`class_attribute` method](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/class_attribute)? Currently it's just ignoring them.

An example:

```
class Base
  class_attribute :defaults

  self.defaults = { foo: 'bar' }
end
```

Comment: can't a normal attr tag do ? `# @attr [Hash] defaults The default values of something`

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to trigger any documentation. I'm thinking I need to write an extension to YARD

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using a [group tag](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#group) is a good solution

```
# @!group Class Attributes
# @!attribute [rw]
# Stores some value
class_attribute :my_atttribute
# @!endgroup
```